# How to run JUnit tests suite in Ant?

Tags: ant, junit, selenium-webdriver

i have such junit tests suite for selenium tests:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Test1.class, Test2.class})
public class TestSuite {
}
```

I want to run test suit via ant, so I add such target:

```
<property environment="environm"/>
<property name="ROOT_PATH" value="../../../../.."/>
<property name="ECLIPSE" value="${ROOT_PATH}/eclipse-kepler/eclipse"/>
<property name="junit" value="junit"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<path id="JUnit.library>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE}/plugins/org.junit_4.11.0.v201303080030/junit.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${ECLIPSE}/plugins/org.hamcrest.core_1.3.0.v201303031735.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="Tests.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <path refid="JUnit.library"/>
    <pathelement location="${ROOT_PATH}/selenium-server-standalone-2.37.0.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="TestSuite">
    <mkdir dir="${junit}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <sysproperty key="variable" value="${value}"/>
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <batchtest todir="${junit}">
      <fileset dir="src">
             <include name="**/TestSuite.class"/>
          </fileset>
        </batchtest>
        <classpath refid="Tests.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
```

I run such command:

```
ant build TestSuite -Dvariable="value"
```

But tests not runs at all.This is output:

```
C:\Selenium>ant build TestSuite -Dvariable="value"
Buildfile: C:\Selenium\build.xml

build-subprojects:

init:

build-project:
  [echo] Selenium: C:\Selenium\build.xml

build:

TestSuite:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

I'm new to ant. What I did wrong?

Comment: I have updated build.xml

Comment: I think your fileset is empty. Try with <fileset dir="bin">, since as it seems you compile your code to the bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

Position the  classpath like below

```
<target name="TestSuite">
<mkdir dir="${junit}"/>
<junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
    <sysproperty key="variable" value="${value}"/>
    <formatter type="xml"/>

  <classpath refid="Tests.classpath"/>
    <batchtest todir="${junit}">
  <fileset dir="src">
         <include name="**/TestSuite.class"/>
      </fileset>
    </batchtest>

</junit>
```